# Regex using JQuery inquiry

Tags: jquery, regex, web

Using jQuery in this format in the following format:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call($("noscript+script")).map(function (v) {
    return v.textContent;
})
```

on the following webpage: http://www.redcoon.it/B404813-StarTech-ST122UTPAEU-Estensore-segnale_Altri-Accessori

I am trying to query just the price of the product, but I am not sure what regex I need to use to get just the price from the big result that I get when I run that line of code above on the webpage

I tried this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call($("noscript+script")).map(function (v) {
    return v.textContent.replace(/[^\d\d\d\.\d\d]/gi, "");
})
```

but then I got all the other numbers and periods as well. Please help

Comment: Post an example of the text content in your question and what you want to extract.

Comment: Unknown website, what if it contain virii? Why can't you just post the example text you want to extract.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
\d+\.?\d+
```

This matches 1 or more digits, followed by an optional decimal point (remove the `?` if you want to *require* the decimal point), followed by 1 or more digits.

```
var reg = /(\d+\.?\d+)/

var text = "sdg gsfdgdf gsg. rsgrdg. sgrgsrg sioig. sgrsrg 12.34 sergsrg. grgrgss gsgrmnoijr sikmg. rgsrgsrg 5.33 grsrgrg srgsrg.";

console.log(reg.exec(text));
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5CJ7/)

What you'll see logged is an array with all your prices in them.

You can modify to restrict the number of characters by replacings the `+` with an appropriate quantifier. So to match what your original seemed to suggest:

```
var reg = /([^\d]\d{3}\.\d{2})/
```

Matches 3 numbers, a (now required) decimal place and then 2 more numbers. Note the `[^\d]` stops it from matching the last 5 digits in a longer number, for example 1122.44.

Edit: If you need to match single digits as @JoaoRaposo suggested, you can do:

```
 var reg = /(\d+\.?\d*)/
```

Comment: That won't match singular digits like '1' or '5'

Comment: @JoaoRaposo: No, but that didn't seem to be what the OP wanted anyway. It's easy enough make the second group optional and then it will.